# How to make aditional custom validation in Laravel request object?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I need to make some custom validation in Laravel request object, but dont know how to do it. Documentation shows only example in controller. I want to have all validation logic in request object. Here is my code whare I try to make some logic after validation, but it does not work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Event;


use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;


class EventRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            "event_name" => "required|unique:events|max:255",
            "company_id" => "exists:companies",
            "start_date" => "required|regex:/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/",
            "start_time" => "regex:/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/",
            "end_date" => "required|regex:/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/",
            "end_time" => "regex:/^\d{2}:\d{2}$/",
        ];

        return $rules;
    }


    public function after()
    {
        $this->validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {

            $data = $validator->safe();

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                // Translations where keys are like title:en, description:sk
                if ( str_contains($key, 'title') && $value && strlen($value) > 250 ) {
                    $validator->errors()->add('title', "$key has to have max of 250 signs.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Custom validation rules are documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: I want to use Request object hook passedValidation()

Comment: `passedValidation` is not a place to do additional validation because it's the point where validation has already passed. `after` should work but I don't know why you'd want to do it this way instead of validating the `title` attribute from within the rules. Maybe you can  share your real use case because here you are trying to just use `[ 'title' => 'max:250' ]` in a very convoluted way

Comment: Because title is not the key. It can be title:en or title:sk it has dynamic suffix. Thats the rearson why why I check str_contains. How can I do it within rules?

Comment: As I said, `after` should be working. Check the request object. It's possible `:` get replaced with something else. Also `add('title'` should be `add($key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for request object is to use withValidation hook in request object.

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    $input = $this->all();

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        // Translations have dynamic keys like title:en, title:sk
        if ( str_contains($key, 'title') && $value && strlen($value) > 250 ) {
            $validator->errors()->add($key, "$key has to have max of 250 signs.");
        }
    }

    // Check if there are any errors
    if ( $validator->errors()->first() ) {
        throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }
}
```